# Data no SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Como faço para aplicar uma função no SQL ORACLE que me traga apenas registros do mês atual?
obs.: eu tenho uma coluna data no formato data (ex.: 13/09/18).

No sql server eu aplicava a função abaixo e funcionada perfeitamente:

```
DAT_REFERENCIA>= DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE())-0,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o WHERE assim:

```
WHERE trunc( DAT_REFERENCIA, 'MM' ) = trunc( sysdate, 'MM' )
```

Vai pegar a data atual do `sysdate` (como `getdate()` no `sql-server`)

EDIT: para pegar o mês atual e o anterior, pode usar o `between`:

```
WHERE DAT_REFERENCIA BETWEEN  add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-1) AND SYSDATE
```

Comment: Ricardo, fiz dessa forma que você falou e rodou legal. E seu eu quiser puxar o mes passado e o mes atual?

Comment: editei a pergunta e adicionei isso lá :)

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo. Funcionou certinho. Abs.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, utilize o a função `EXTRACT` para o comando que pega a data atual no Oracle que é o `sysdate`. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
Select extract(month from sysdate) as MES_ATUAL from dual ;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela Ajuda.